# Javascript: toggle change content of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple javascript code that changing the content of **span** elements.

Now this script working only for the first one **span** element. How can I fix it to make changeable all spans with only one no multiple javascript script?

**MY CODE:**

```js
const span = document.querySelector('span');

span.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.innerHTML === "Zavolajte nám ihneď") {
    event.target.innerHTML = "+421 911 111 111";
  } else {
    event.target.innerHTML = "Zavolajte nám ihneď";
  }
})
```

```html
<span>Zavolajte nám ihneď</span><br><br>
<span>Zavolajte nám ihneď</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `querySelectorAll` and then loop over the returned collection:

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');

spans.forEach(span => span.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.innerHTML === "Zavolajte nám ihneď") {
    event.target.innerHTML = "+421 911 111 111";
  } else {
    event.target.innerHTML = "Zavolajte nám ihneď";
  }
}));
```

```html
<span>Zavolajte nám ihneď</span><br><br>
<span>Zavolajte nám ihneď</span>
```

`querySelector` only returns the first element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.